# How to deal with cheat avoidance and trusted client issue

Tags: unity, networking, client-server

I hope not to be off-topic here.

At the moment I'm dealing with networking programming for the game I'm working on and I found different possible scenarios.

I started to build code using a Platform as a Service such as Photon Unity Network which offers a quite simple system to sync players through its cloud.

The problem is that by using the cloud you must have at least a trusted client in order to prevent cheating from players.

I wish I could learn what is best to deal with this problem considering that opting for a client/server structure would be the best but I'm a bit worried about rental/purchase pricing. Is there a cheap way to have a working game server?

Comment: If people want to play your game, they will host the server themselves, as long as you offer the server alongside your game.   Unless you are a AAA title, this is typically how it is done.

Comment: I agree, bot @Jon 's comment and the duplicate question answer quite good to my question. It's ok for me to close it. If just Jon wants to post his comment as answer I could accept it

Comment: Cheating isn't specific to "cloud" servers.